# How can I get the scheduled shutdown time in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Suppose I schedule a shutdown/restart in Windows, e.g.

```
shutdown /r /f /t 300
```

Is there a way that I can query how much time is left or at what time the restart will happen?

I can abort the shutdown,

```
shutdown /a
```

so, I presume that Windows is keeping track of this independently of the shell I used to schedule the shutdown.

How can I get this information? Basically, I'd like to be able to know how much time is left (or if there's an active shutdown currently scheduled)?

Answer (score 1):

https://superuser.com/questions/317051/in-windows-7-how-do-i-know-when-a-computer-is-scheduled-to-be-shutdown

https://superuser.com/questions/1028374/determine-whether-a-shutdown-is-pending

Check out the above links for reference.

I did some google FU, and there does not a appear to be a direct way to get the information you want.  You ether have to some querying with power-shell or look in the event logs.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/540602)